# How to Use Github Actions to Clone Repo to Network File System?

Tags: github-actions

I have a repo that I want to be cloned to a network file system location every time a push occurs. I was able to do this through the terminal:

```
rm -rf  //Target/Location
git clone https://github.com/jlaacsohbin/temp.git //Target/Location
```

But it does not work when I add it to a Github action. No errors occur, it just seems to do nothing. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Please show your workflow

Comment: If you want to have a look, I've recently built [a new version](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/clone-github-repo-action/issues/3#issuecomment-1115980567) to a Github Action that would allow the user to inform the path to clone a specific repo. It might be helpful in your case (and could also give me a feedback to release this version or not).